# how to correctly write a function

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

how to correctly write a function for a variable (custom javascript) in google tag manager?
from this:

```
function() {
  'items': eshop.product.options.length === 0 ? [{
     'id': eshop.product.id,
     'google_business_vertical': 'retail'
      }] : eshop.product.options.map(function (option) {
        return {
          'id': eshop.product.id.toString() + '_' + option.id,
           'google_business_vertical': 'retail'
         };
      }) 
}
```

still have some error.
Thanks for help.

Petiman

Comment: Your function is not a function. You haven't declared a variable, you don't pass arguments to function. 

If you run your code in browser's console, you will get specific errors. You can write a function by fixing errors one by one.

Answer (score 1):

ok I got it..

```
function () {
var prods = eshop.product;
return  eshop.product.options.length === 0 ? [{
            'id': eshop.product.id,
            'google_business_vertical': 'retail'
        }] : eshop.product.options.map(function (option) {
            return {
                'id': eshop.product.id.toString() + '_' + option.id,
                'google_business_vertical': 'retail'
            };
        }) 
}
```